# How to create a navigation menu for existing site using HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-helper, helper

I am pretty new to coding. My boss is asking me to add a navigation bar to the existing website so all the services are hidden in the Service option. Can anyone know a quick way to add this?
We are using purely HTML and CSS for our website only. Hope to hear any advice.
[Image of Existing Menu here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WvEZ.png)

Comment: Nobody is going to do your work for you, what have you tried yourself?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are asking for a element to be hidden, there are a couple of ways you can do that, but the simplest one is to use `display: none` attribute or the `visibility: hidden` attribute in css. You can visit [this](https://careerkarma.com/blog/css-hide-element/) link for a step by step explanation and guide.